# Can I directly use my own loading screen and models directly instead of submitting to dota 2 workshop?

Tags: dota-2

I have my own models/cosmetics that I have made.
I also have some loading screens of my own.
Is there a way I can use them without submitting to workshop?
I would like to share them with my close friends.
Is there a way to share them without going through the workshop?

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible as all kind of these things comes to dota 2 by updates; so you need to submitting then gaining votes then dota 2 will release them in their update ;).

Answer (score 2):

Although this might be possible by replacing certain game files it's not advisable because Valve would likely consider it as cheating.